# Is there any way to automate the process in Labview

Tags: labview

I have an application build on labview for sensors. It takes files and gives output as .cal files. It takes the maximum pressure and temperature values and output the sensor data with minimum errors. I want to automate this process

This application is very old written in Labview. Should I make the whole application in another platform or language, or is there any other way to automate the error reduction and giving file as output in Labview itself

I want to automate the whole process. I should be able to enter pressure and temperature and it should give me the sensor value in the end.

Comment: If you have access to the source code you can do all kinds of stuff, including automation. If you're stuck with binary file, it can be called by other programs as a part of an automation sequence. Any manual type of interaction would need to be accounted for and automated as well. All told, it sounds like a pretty simple application and could probably be written from scratch with little fuss.

Comment: Thanks for reply Dave, Actually, the application is pretty big having a lot of calculation of pressure and temperature for sensors. Can You suggest any other platform where I can make the whole application again? Also,  the one part I have to work on which is to automatically change the values displayed on the array of labview and change them automatically so that the error is minimized. and save those values in file.

Comment: If I had to rewrite, I would do it in LabVIEW. If you feel more comfortable with another language, use that one instead. If you're taking over an old project, perhaps there is an old copy of LabVIEW laying around. If you can track down the serial number of this copy, an upgrade can be purchased at a huge discount from NI.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the reply. I have decided that I will work with labview only. i got the access of new labview also . I have one more question. can labview change the values displayed in the graph to minimize error. For example, my graph displays the pressure values in different test cases and error rate with those pressure . I need to change the pressure values so that such that error is minimized. The application should change the pressure value and give me new pressure value so that error is minimized is what I require.

Comment: It sounds like you want to programmatically change the scale of your x and y axes. If this is so, LabVIEW can do this with ease.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that. I want to change the value of x axis and y axis so that my error is minimized and I want the new x axis and y axis value. Can you guide me how can I do that ? I am new to labview so where to write the logic?

Comment: [NI's page on customizing graphs](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/lvconcepts/customizing_graphs_and_charts/) is a good place to start. It sounds like you're very new to LabVIEW so you would probably benefit from watching [some tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=labview+tutorial).

Comment: Thanks Dave. Will ask again if any help needed.